# How to chunk encrypted large files

Tags: spring-batch

How do I decrypt & chunk large encrypted files with below restrictions?

1. Do not want to decrypt and store file temporarily in file system because of sensitivity of data.
2. Do not want to decrypt and store entire data in memory before chunking just because of memory space.